# Cypress E2E debug mode - endless re-fetch on hover

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, istanbul

When I run `npx cypress open` on my React project, it opens the debug window, where I can see each test and inspect each snapshot.

The test in question is pretty simple

```
describe("Scheduled changes table", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    cy.fixture("scheduledChangesList.json").as("scheduledChangesList");

  });
 

  it("Shows Confirmation modal after selecting Cancel", () => {

    cy.intercept("GET", "/scheduled-changes/api/v1/scheduled-changes", {

      fixture: "scheduledChangesList.json",

    }).as("getScheduledChangesList");
 

    cy.visit("/");

  });
});
```

It mounts a component, which uses a hook to make a GET request as soon as it renders.
Here's the hook

```
export async function getScheduledChanges(id) {
  const response = await fetch(`/scheduled-changes/api/v1/scheduled-changes${id}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

My problem is when I inspect the snapshots when the tests finish and I keep my mouse over something in the "After all" section, it starts making infinite fetches of the request that is in the component's hook. It looks like this:

[image]

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found out that is was?

Comment: @MichielBruggenwirth nope, I even opened a thread in their Discord, back when I made this post, but still no fix